# Office365 notification operations

Tags: office365, office365api

I am attempting to use the renew functionality of the Office365 notification operations.  I am able to successfully do POST (to create subscriptions) and GET (to get info on a subscription) operations, but when I attempt to call renew with PATCH, I get a 404.  The 404 is a confusing response to me because my requests succeed when I use the same url with GET instead of PATCH.  Has anybody experienced something similar?

Here is some psudo code showing the problem:

```
url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/#{user_email}/subscriptions/#{subscriptionId}"
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{token}"]

response = request(url, headers, "GET")
response.status_code // 200
response.data // JSON describing subscription

data = {"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",     Expiration: -3.days.ago}.to_json
response = request(url, headers, data, "PATCH")
response.status_code // 404
response.body // empty
```

Here is the relevant documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations#NotificationoperationsRenewsubscription

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, the correct property in the JSON payload should be `SubscriptionExpirationDateTime`, but you have `Expiration`. If you change that does it work? 404 seems incorrect if that's the issue though :)